# After grouping filter each group with condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have dataset that can be grouped with following:

```
  df.groupby(df.batch.str[:7])
```

different group sizes are

```
df.groupby(df.batch.str[:7]).size().unique()

 array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

lets say I will take any group with size 4,

```
    col1     col2  col3
0   rt_2345  NaN   fine
1   rt_2345  3.0   good
2   rt_2345  4.0   ok
3   rt_2345  46.0  bad
```

In each group I want to filter where `col3 == 'OK'` and *one row above it*.

Desired out put in this group would be

```
    1   rt_2345  3.0   good
    2   rt_2345  4.0   ok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare actual and shifted value by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with `ok`, chain mask by `|` for regex `OR` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[(df.col3 == 'ok') | (df.col3.shift(-1) == 'ok')]
print (df)
      col1  col2  col3
1  rt_2345   3.0  good
2  rt_2345   4.0    ok
```

If need solution for compare per groups use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
df = df[(df.col3 == 'ok') | (df.groupby(df.batch.str[:7]).col3.shift(-1) == 'ok')]
```